# Arduino multi-dimensional array crash

Tags: arduino, processing

I have a block of code that does something to this effect:

```
int pieceX = 0;
int pieceY = 0;

int board[8][47] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

if (pieceX > 0 && pieceY < 46) {

  /* If I remove this it doesn't crash */
  if (board[pieceX-1][pieceY] == 0 && board[pieceX][pieceY+1] == 0) {
    pieceX -= 1;
  }
  /*-----------------------------------*/
}
```

As far as I can tell, I'm initializing my array correctly and I'm staying within the index bounds.  I don't work much with Processing or Arduino, so I'm hoping it's something simple / obvious.

Edit:  Hmm..  I just made a minimalistic test version with this code, and it doesn't crash.  So, it's something to do with the code not in this example.  Damn.  Going to try to zero in on those lines.  (My bad for posting this before properly isolating the problem code.)  While this accurately describes the problem, it does not reproduce it.  Strange bug.

Edit 2:  This doesn't crash:

```
if (buttonA == HIGH) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
    if (board[0][0] == 0) {
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't crash:

```
if (buttonA == HIGH) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
    pieceX -= 1;
  }
}
```

This DOES crash:

```
if (buttonA == HIGH) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
    if (board[0][0] == 0) {
      pieceX -= 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what's going on?  ButtonA is never HIGH, so.. the code I'm tweaking shouldn't even matter (it all verifies and uploads fine.)

Edit 3: This crashes:

```
if (buttonA == HIGH) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
    if (board[0][0] == 0) {
      pieceX -= 1;
    }
  }
}
```

This DOES NOT:

```
if (0 == 1) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
    if (board[0][0] == 0) {
      pieceX -= 1;
    }
  }
}
```

This crashes:

```
if (buttonA == HIGH) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
    if (board[0][0] == 0) {
      pieceX = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

This DOES NOT:

```
if (buttonA == HIGH) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
      pieceX = 1;
  }
}
```

AND THIS DOES NOT:

```
if (buttonA == HIGH) {
  if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {
    if (board[0][0] == 0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Edit, [here](http://pastebin.com/LtcAQ97z)'s the full source code.  I'm only a few hours into a black and white Dr Mario clone.  I never write in this language, so.. potentially a bit sloppy.  More of a random learning experiment in processing / video game hardware / arduino.

Comment: Can `pieceX` be a value bigger than 7 (You only check whether it is above 0)?

Comment: In my larger production version of the code, pieceX and pieceY are currently always equal to zero.  I can expand that initial bounds check to `if (pieceX > 0 && pieceX < 8 && pieceY > 0 && pieceY < 46) {` and it will still crash.  In my logic, the arduino shouldn't even be thinking about that inner conditional because the outer one is alawys false.  I'm not getting any useful debug info.  Maybe there's a way to find out more?

Comment: How do you know buttonA is not HIGH? Without more context it will be hard to figure out the problem.

Comment: @Craig Good call.  Let me try switching it out with "if (0==1)" and see what that does.  I can post the full source code, but it'll be less clear.

Comment: @Craig That is definitely a clue.

Comment: Ah, this is getting too long and confusing of a post.  Hmmmmmm.

Comment: Your clrPiece function is being called with 0,0 so it is calling set_pixel with a negative value. This is likely overwriting something inside the TV library.

Comment: Good catch.  Hmm.  I modified the array to a 4x30 and added checks for positive numbers.  The issue persists.  It happens when I try to read board[0][0].  Weird.  http://pastebin.com/x1ZjHEXc

Comment: @arby The fact that `if (0 == 1)` not exhibit the same problem *could* be due to the compiler optimizing it away (since it 'knows' that zero never equals one)...

Comment: @arby When you describe the code as crashing, what happens exactly? Code running on an Arduino won't core dump or equivalent.

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch I normally get TV output (just draws a square.)  Whenever I try to look at my array via a board[0][0] call, I do not.  I'm probably going to have to just really dial back the code and start again.  (I don't use arduino much so I'm not sure where I went wrong.)  This is pretty early in development, but, I'd like to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely looks like you are running out of memory.

```
int board[8][47]
```

consumes 752 bytes of memory. In addition

```
TV.begin(NTSC,120,96);
```

will call

```
char TVout::begin(uint8_t mode, uint8_t x, uint8_t y) {

    // check if x is divisable by 8
    if ( !(x & 0xF8))
            return 1;
    x = x/8;

    screen = (unsigned char*)malloc(x * y * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

which tries to allocate 1440 bytes of memory. 1440 + 752 == 2192 > 2048 == SRAM size of Arduino

So you are running out of memory.

Can you switch int board[8][47] from int to int8_t or uint8_t? This would reduce the memory consumption of the array by 2. However you would still be very tight on memory.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that!  That is definitely it then.  I wish the IDE would throw me an error that explained what was going on.

Comment: Sine TVout allocates the memory dynamically at runtime there is unfortunately no way for the IDE to know that you will be running out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since the issue seems to be erratic, I would guess you are corrupting your stack.

I am not sure which Arduino you are using and how many other variables you have defined.

The array you are creating is 8 * 47 * 2 = 752 bytes, the Arduino Uno has 2048 ram bytes for the stack and all of your variables.

Edit:
Can you temporary reduce the size of the array(maybe 4 * 10) to see if it stops crashing?

Another test you could do is to list the values before you modify them and verify they are all 0.

Comment: Good thinking.  That doesn't seem to be it, however.  This might be more clear.  -- http://pastebin.com/x1ZjHEXc

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like you are running out of memory.
You might be able to use less memory.

It looks like any given board element is either a 0 or 1.

If I am wrong disregard the rest of my statement.
Else you "could" make an array like this.

```
 char board [47];
 first  = 0b00000001;    //binary mask, for binary and
 second = 0b00000010;
 third =  0b00000100;
 ...
```

Then to look up any bit you

```
if (board[33]&second == 0 )     \\you are testing what was called board[2][33]
```

This might help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Currently, it is a 0 or a 1, but... I'm going to have to do 0,1,2,3 as possible values.  Perhaps I could accomplish this with some sort of bitmask.  Tricky.